# RxJava Scheduler usage breaks Robolectric test

Tags: android, junit, robolectric, observable

I'm trying to test some method using Robolectric (3.1-rc1)

/* Method code */

```
public void sendSomething(String prop1, String prop2){
Observable<SomeResponse> service = mSomeWebServiceAPI.login(new SomeRequest(prop1, prop2));
Subscription subscription = service.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(response -> {
        if(isSuccess()){
            // ... some code && inserting data to sqlite
            if (isViewPresent()) getView().onSuccess();
        } else {
            if (isViewPresent()) getView().onError();
        }
    }, err -> {
        if (isViewPresent()) getView().onError();
    });
}
```

/* Test code */

```
@Test
public void testSending() throws Exception {
   mController.sendSomething("", "");
   assertFalse(mRepository.findAll().isEmpty()); // 1
   verify(mController.getView(), atLeastOnce()).onSuccess(); // 2
}
```

Because of threading inside tested method I've got this errors on line 1:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:64)
at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:74)
```

And this on line 2:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
newInterface.onSuccess();
-> at com.example.MyTestClass.testSending
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I've tried http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2015/09/13/testing-rxjava-observables-subscriptions/ solution, but for me it's not working.

My verify should check if method onSuccess() was called. But this method is inside Observable.onSubscribe, so it should run synchronous to call verify() only when subscription will complete.

Comment: What are you actually asking? Trying to achieve etc?

Comment: My verify should check if method onSuccess() was called. But this method is inside Observable.onSubscribe, so it should run synchronous to call verify() only when subscription will complete.

Comment: Please edit your question with your question

Comment: I don't see any `Asserts` in your test code. Are you sure it fails in this test?

Comment: This test passed when I change Schedulers.newThread() to Schedulers.immediate();